# Error:Failed to resolve: :estimote-sdk-preview: <a href="openFile">Open File</a> in estimote iBeacon Sdk

Tags: android, sdk, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, estimote

Steps i have done following [this](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK) are as follows:-

1.Create libs directory inside your project and copy there estimote-sdk-preview.aar.

2.In your build.gradle add flatDir entry to your repositories

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

3.Add dependency to Estimote SDK.

All needed permissions (*BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and INTERNET*) and services will be merged from SDK's AndroidManifest.xml to your application's AndroidManifest.xml.

```
dependencies {
  compile(name:'estimote-sdk-preview', ext:'aar')
}
```

Ater doing all this...i get the following error:

**Error:(31, 0) Project with path ':estimote-sdk-preview' could not be found in project ':app'.**
How can i solve it

Answer (score 1):

Can you double check if you downloaded aar file correctly. Just open it as zip archive and there should be some contents.

It might be similar problem as [described here](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/issues/36) where you downloaded html file instead of aar file.

Comment: Can you than just clone Android-SDK and run demos directly from there?

Comment: yes...have you worked on any apps implementing iBeacon estimote

Comment: If SDK Demos works for you, you can pick it from there.

Comment: i have found my mistake and i have solved the above question....Do you have any good tutorials to share on ibeacon app implementation...